# Bootstrap Modal in separate view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently doing an MVC application in .NET.

As for now, within my `_Layout.cshtml` page i have a login modal that is made with bootstrap. (I want to use a specific model with this modal)

The thing is, i have already passed a model to my `_Layout.cshtml` page, which means that i need to separate my modal from the `_Layout.cshtml` page to another view, in which i there will be able to invoke my model.

This leads me to my question:

How do i separate my modal to another view, and still be able to call it in my _Layout.

Assumption: I could just toss my modal to my index view, but that would just move the problem to my index view instead.

Comment: In your layout use `@Html.Action(...)` to call a `[ChildActionOnly]` method that returns a partial view of your modal (your `_Layout.cshtml` file should not contains a `@model ...` statement unless its a base view model used by all view that use that layout)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, makes sense now!

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are far from being fair with me. I see you mocking every single post i make. I feel that you are getting personal with me

Comment: What are you talking about? And what make you think I am _mocking_ you?

Comment: You are marking my question a duplicate. You did the same on my previous question. - it is furthermore not the same question.

Comment: It is a duplicate - it shows you how to handle this (as per my previous comment - i.e. use `@Html.Action()` to call a server method). There is no point repeating the same answer to the same questions over and over again (which is the purpose of marking questions as duplicates). Just because your creating a partial for a form as opposed to creating a partial for a menu as per the dupe makes no difference.